# Python accumulate errors or secondary data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've trying to find a good way to accumulate errors in case when function returns two values `(result, errors)`

Example:

```
def do_something(inp):
"""just for example"""
    if type(inp) is not str:
        return None, 'inp is not string'
    return inp.upper(), None

results_dict = {}
errors = []

r, e = do_something(handler1(inp1))
results_dict[inp1] = r
if e:
    errors.append(r)
r, e = do_something(handler2(inp2))
results_dict[inp2] = r
if e:
    errors.append(r)
# and so on
```

Is there the right way to accumulate errors in one string
like this pseudocode

```
errors = ErrorsAccumulator()
results_dict = {}
results_dict[inp1], errors = do_something(handler1(inp1))
results_dict[inp2], errors = do_something(handler2(inp2))
# and so on
```

I can't use loop for it because there is a lot different handlers

Comment: I wrote up an answer, then realized you have something odd with `errors`. If there's an error, you want to append `r`? `r` would be `None` if there's an error according to your example.

Comment: When you're accumulating errors, the object `errors` is going to be replaced by the second value returned by `do_something`, could you provide an example of how the `ErrorAccumulator` is defined?

Comment: @Carcigenicate, yes, I want to collect errors and result, he real code is much more complex and in case of error the results won't be `None` in all cases.

Comment: @torresmateo, there is no definition of `ErrorAccumulator`, I provided it just as pseudocode, just to clarify what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, what you want to do is collect outputs and results in 2 different lists.

As it is written right now, the code will simply *replace* whatever the variable `errors` contains:

```py
errors = ErrorsAccumulator()
results_dict = {}
results_dict[inp1], errors = do_something(handler1(inp1))
results_dict[inp2], errors = do_something(handler2(inp2))
```

Assuming that `errors` is a list, you could instead do this:

```py
def unpack(t): 
    # this function will unpack the result and error of 
    # your calls to do_something
    return t[0], [t[1]]

errors = []
results_dict = {}
results_dict[inp1], errors[len(errors):] = unpack(do_something(handler1(inp1)))
results_dict[inp2], errors[len(errors):] = unpack(do_something(handler2(inp2)))
```

However, that is not very clean (in my opinion). What I propose you do instead is:

```py
inputs_results_errors = []
inputs_results_errors.append(inp1, *do_something(handler1(inp1)))
inputs_results_errors.append(inp1, *do_something(handler2(inp1)))

# append many more ...

# and then separate into lists or dicts

inputs, results, errors = zip(*inputs_results_errors)
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks, that what I wanted.

Comment: If my asnwer helped you solve the question, please accept it :) I'm glad it worked